# AMD APU graphics driver hardware detection - Manjaro

Tags: drivers, amd, manjaro, amd-graphics

I have a laptop that is running an AMD Radeon HD 7660G. I installed Manjaro after shredding the hard drive of the previous installation and it booted to a black screen. I attributed this problem to a problem with drivers. The wiki has lots of information for using pci or usb graphics *cards*, but I can't seem to find any information on drivers for AMD integrated graphics. So far I've tried:

```
sudo mhwd -a pci free 0300
> Skipping already installed config 'video-ati' for device: 0000:00:01.0 (0300:1992:9900) Display controller ATI Technologies Inc

aticonfig --initial --adapter=all -f
bash: aticonfig: command not found
```

and

```
$ sudo mhwd -a pci nonfree 0300
```

I rebooted and lost the output, command was successful and installed amd catalyst

```
$ aticonfig --initial --adapter=all -f
```

configured the system successfully, I don't have the output. If its necessary for a diagnosis I'll run it again

After running both commands I booted and got past grub and the loading screen, only to meet a sedentary black screen. Is the issue with backlighting or with the drivers? Is there a specific method to handle integrated graphics drivers?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Exchange. Please take a minute to familiarize yourself with our markup, it's different from the one you used in your post. You can use the buttons on top of the edit box to insert most common features. Click on the `?` at the top right of the edit box to see formatting help. Note that you can see a rendered preview just below the edit box. I tried to edit your post, but since I don't know the markup language that you used, I may have confused some markup with command output.

Answer (score 1):

> aticonfig --initial --adapter=all -f bash: aticonfig: command not
>   found[/code]

This leads me to believe that you have not installed the fglrx package.  This is the first thing you need to do.

**Even if you have already done so perform these commands...**

```
sudo cp /etc/X11/xorg.conf /etc/X11/xorg.conf.BAK
sudo apt-get remove --purge fglrx*
sudo reboot

sudo apt-get install linux-headers-generic
sudo apt-get install fglrx fglrx-amdcccle
sudo amdconfig --initial
sudo reboot
```

Then if that does not resolve your problem please issue `fglrxinfo` and paste the output here.